# Flutter video_player how to deal with temp data

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-video-player

I would like to stream a video that I receive via the **SRT-Protocol** (https://www.srtalliance.org/).

Unfortunately the flutter *video_player* ***does not support the SRT protocol***. As the protocol is written in C/C++ I implemented a wrapper with dart:ffi and now I can connect to my Server that is streaming a video (apple h264) with SRT.
I can receive the packets from the stream but now I don't know how to play a video from these packets.
My approach so far: creating a temporary file

```
var dir = Directory.systemTemp.createTempSync();
var temp = File("${dir.path}/$fileName").createSync();
```

then write to incoming packets to the temp file and pass it to the video_player as file.

```
temp.writeAsBytesSync(receivedPackets*emphasized text*, mode: FileMode.append, flush: false);
```

The video_player is not opening the file (h264) and I receive the following error message.

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: Cannot Open, null, null)
```

I would appreciate any help in order to solve this issue!